# Algorithm to iterate through image pixels

Tags: algorithm

I'm sure something for this already exists so I figure why reinvent the wheel.

Does anyone know of an algorithm that will iterate through pixels in an image from the top left towards the bottom right.

So first it will check: `(0, 0)`

Then: `(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)`

Then `(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (0, 2)`

... and so on....

Looking for the most efficient algorithm for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Efficiency is not a concern here. This is just a for loop. It is impossible to do better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to iterate in this manner:

```
1 4 9
  ↑ ↑
2→3 8
    ↑
5→6→7

...
```

This is just a for-loop:

```
for radius in range(squareImage.width):
    for col in range(radius):
        yield (radius, col)
    for row in range(radius):
        yield (radius-row, radius)
    yield (0, radius)
```

Efficiency is not a concern here. It is impossible to do better than linear-in-number-of-pixels (like this) because you have to visit every pixel.

Comment: and the complexity of this is O(N^2) and i dont see how you can do any better than this.

Comment: @DarthVader: since there are O(N^2) yield operations required, it is impossible do better.

Comment: @sdcvvc yes. that s also what i said:)